# Authenticated referral popup dialog not being triggered

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have the Enhanced Auth Dialog setting turned on for my Facebook app. I've added "user_likes" and "friend_likes" to "Authenticated Referrals" in my settings.

I check my app list - my app is not in my list of installed apps. When I search for the app, it appears in the search list. I click it, but no Authenticated Referral dialog pops up.

Is there a setting or step in the process that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for the help.